# Why methodName (Class<? extends interfaceName> name) works but methodName (Class<interfaceName> name) doesn't

Tags: java, spring

i'm confused on why:

**HATEOASController interface:**

```
public interface HATEOASController {
    ResponseEntity<?> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    ResponseEntity<?> findById(Long id);
}
```

**EstadoController:**

```
     public class EstadoController implements HATEOASController {
           //other methods

       @GetMapping(value={"/", ""})
       public ResponseEntity<?> findAll(Pageable pageable){
      
            Page<Estado> estados = estadoService.findAll(pageable);
            estados.forEach(i->{               //**HERE**
                                              //   \/
                HATEOASBuilder.linksBuilder(i, EstadoController.class);
                HATEOASBuilder.linksBuilderWithMap(i.getCidades());
            });
        return new ResponseEntity(estados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**HATEOASBuilder:**

```
public static void linksBuilder (HATEOASBuilder estado, Class<? extends HATEOASController> ControllerClass){
//methods}
```

This above works, but like this below:

**HATEOASBuilder:**

```
public static void linksBuilder (HATEOASBuilder estado, Class<HATEOASController> ControllerClass){
    //methods}
```

doesn't work (Required type:Class< HATEOASController >, Provided:Class< EstadoController >)

Using interface argument doesn't mean that i can pass any class implementing it? (EstadoController in this case), i don't get why the extends is needed

Comment: Because `Class<EstadoController>` is not a subtype of `Class<HATEOASController>`.

Comment: I don't get it, exactly, EstadoController is not a subtype of HATEOASController, however, upon using Class<? extends HATEOASController> it works

Comment: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745306)